# R: reading the code of 2nd level functions in packages

Tags: r

When I load the [acss package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acss/index.html), I'm able to read its `entropy` function by simply writing `entropy` in the Console.

```
entropy
function (string) 
{
    check_string(string)
    splitted <- strsplit(string, "")
    y <- lapply(splitted, function(x) as.vector(table(x)))
    l <- nchar(string)
    y <- mapply(function(x, y) x/y, y, l, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    names(y) <- string
    vapply(y, function(x) -sum(x * log2(x)), 0)
}
<environment: namespace:acss>
```

However, if I try to read the first function inside entropy, `check_string`, writing its name in the console I get

```
check_string
Error: object 'check_string' not found
```

How can I read the source of check_string?

Comment: The answer there is long, the section you want is the one on functions calling unexported functions.

Comment: Short answer: `acss:::check_string`